# Warning Regarding extcodehash in Remix for openzeppelin-contracts

Tags: solidity, remix

I have compiled the openzeppelin-contracts code in Remix IDE. Meanwhile, I have obtained the following warning.

> Warning: The "extcodehash" instruction is not supported by the VM version "byzantium" you are currently compiling for. It will be interpreted as an invalid instruction on this VM. assembly { codehash := extcodehash(account) }

I am obtaining this warning for all recent versions of the EVM, and not just the byzantium one. I have tried to search for a solution regarding this warning, but without success. Would anyone know how to "fix" this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the contract imports from the OpenZeppelin Contracts GitHub master branch which needs a later compiler version.

You should only use code published in an official release of OpenZeppelin Contracts, the latest release is [2.3](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/releases/tag/v2.3.0). When importing via GitHub on Remix you can specify the release tag, (otherwise you will get the latest code in the master branch).

The warning is caused by:
[Compiler 0.5.3 has a default EVM version of `byzantium`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/using-the-compiler.html#target-options) whilst [Compiler 0.5.11 has a default EVM version of `petersburg`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.11/using-the-compiler.html#target-options).  You may also want to use Compiler version 0.5.11.

The imports using version 2.3.0 of OpenZeppelin Contracts would be:

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.3.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.3.0/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

Alternatively to using Remix, have a look at the [Getting Started](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/) guide for information on how to setup a development environment.

If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/

Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin

Comment: Thank you abcoathup. I am compiling the smart contrat found at the link hereafter (using the 0.5.3 Compiler Version): https://medium.com/openberry/erc721-vue-js-cryptokitties-like-dapp-in-under-10-minutes-5115efc9e0bb

Comment: Updated my answer now that I can see the contract.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time abcoathup!

Comment: I create a Pull Request to get the code for the tutorial you used updated: https://github.com/openberry-ac/cryptovipers/pull/3
I created an Issue to update the pragma Solidity version on `Address.sol` in OpenZeppelin Contracts https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/issues/1897

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you again abcoathup.